# Plot a heart in R

Tags: r, parametric-equations, polar-coordinates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equation-driven smoothly shaded concentric shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542825/equation-driven-smoothly-shaded-concentric-shapes)

How could I plot a symmetrical heart in R like I plot a circle (using plotrix) or a rectangle?

I'd like code for this so that I could actually do it for my self and to be able to generalize this to similar future needs.  I've seen even more elaborate plots than this so it's pretty doable, it's just that I lack the knowledge to do it.

Comment: Valetines day is still 3 months off, cupid must have hit you pretty hard.

Comment: Not sure about implementation in `r`, but you'll likely be interested in [cardiod polar equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cardioid.html), and / or [other routes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html).

Comment: I used the last eqn in the Wolfram page in the above link as the source of the parametric eqn and just calculated over 0 -> 2pi.

Comment: For a shaded version, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6542825/269476

Comment: it's not really an exact duplicate, is it?  there are just some overlapping answers ...

Comment: I'm voting to close, but it should remain un-deleted for it's excellent answers and more Google-able title.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is an example of plotting a "parametric equation", i.e. a pairing of two separate equations for x and y that share a common parameter. You can find many common curves and shapes that can be written within such a framework.

```
dat<- data.frame(t=seq(0, 2*pi, by=0.1) )
 xhrt <- function(t) 16*sin(t)^3
 yhrt <- function(t) 13*cos(t)-5*cos(2*t)-2*cos(3*t)-cos(4*t)
 dat$y=yhrt(dat$t)
 dat$x=xhrt(dat$t)
 with(dat, plot(x,y, type="l"))
```

[Other Parametric (and implicit and polar) Heart Eqns](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html)

You also could "heat it up" with using the "fill" capability of the `polygon` function:

```
with(dat, polygon(x,y, col="hotpink"))
```

And if you just want little hearts to sprinkle around at various places, you could use the Symbol font version of "heart" after looking at the `help(points)` page and using the `TestChars` function:

```
points(c(10,-10, -15, 15), c(-10, -10, 10, 10), pch=169, font=5)
```

[image]

Windows users may want to see if adding the Cairo package helps gain access to card symbols including "hearts".( When I tested the TestChars function on the WinXP "side" of my MacPro I did not get hearts, and paging through the "special symbols" in MS-Word did not uncover anything. So I did a search of Rhelp and found a recent posting by Ivo Welch. He was reporting a bug, but they look OK on my machine.) Further note... I think the hearts and diamonds codes in his were reversed.

```
library(Cairo)

clubs <- expression(symbol('\247'))
hearts <- expression(symbol('\251'))
diamonds <- expression(symbol('\250'))
spades <- expression(symbol('\252'))
csymbols <- c(clubs, hearts, diamonds, spades)

plot( 0, xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,2), type="n" )
clr <- c("black", "red", "red", "black") 
for (i in 1:4) {
  hline <- function( yloc, ... ) 
         for (i in 1:length(yloc)) 
             lines( c(-1,6), c(yloc[i],yloc[i]), col="gray")  
              hline(0.9); 
                hline(1.0);
                hline(1.1);
                hline(1.2)  
 text( i, 1, csymbols[i], col=clr[i], cex=5 )  
 text( i, 0.5, csymbols[i], col=clr[i] ) }

# Also try this
plot(1,1)
text(x=1+0.2*cos(seq(0, 2*pi, by=.5)), 
     y=1+0.2*sin(seq(0, 2*pi, by=.5)), 
                  expression(symbol('\251') ) )
```

[image]

Comment: I actually want the little symbols but pch 169 on my machine is the copyright symbol "©". What would I need to do to make a heart symbol with `points(x,y, pch)`? I'm think font family or somthing like that but am unsure of how to approach this.

Comment: The links in my comment (#2) on @aL3xa's answer might be useful ...

Comment: @Tyler Rinker: Define and run the function `TestChars(font=5)` at the end of the examples on the help(points) page. It will print out all the Symbol glyphs for your system that are indexed by the decimal numbers: `c(32:126, 160:254)`

Comment: (+1) for "heating it up"

Comment: Very beautiful shape!

Answer (score 20):

[From a blog post:](http://fancythought.blogspot.com/2011/06/love-formula-heart-shaped-curvy-graph.html)

Solve the parametric equation for y (does SO allow math formatting?)

x^2 + (5y/4-sqrt(abs(x)))^2 = 1

sqrt(1-x^2) = 5y/4 - sqrt(abs(x))

y = 4/5*(sqrt(1-x^2)+sqrt(abs(x)))

```
MASS::eqscplot(0:1,0:1,type="n",xlim=c(-1,1),ylim=c(-0.8,1.5))
curve(4/5*sqrt(1-x^2)+sqrt(abs(x)),from=-1,to=1,add=TRUE,col=2)
curve(4/5*-sqrt(1-x^2)+sqrt(abs(x)),from=-1,to=1,add=TRUE,col=2)
```

[image]

Comment: fair enough.  Do you know an *easy* way to generate MathML?  (I get spoiled by CrossValidated, which automatically renders LaTeX ...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227195/latex-to-mathml-conversion-tools-limitations-and-approaches

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. Here's MetaSO discussion of why MathJax won't be turned on: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000   Appears that the extra half-second to load is not considered worthwhile for those of us using higher level languages where it makes sense. The C-users are calling the shots.

Comment: It might (?) be possible to embed MathJax manually? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865522/which-browsers-do-support-mathml

Answer (score 19):

Simple and ugly hack:

```
plot(1, 1, pch = "♥", cex = 20, xlab = "", ylab = "", col = "firebrick3")
```

Comment: DISCLAIMER: I'm perfectly aware of the fact that this is not what you want, and I'd really like to see the actual code you were looking for. =)

Comment: But this could actually be a very nice starting point if one wanted to use hearts as plotting characters: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886018/using-unicode-dingbat-like-glyphs-in-r-graphics-across-devices-platforms-e and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=heart&preview=entity

Comment: But if walks like a heart and quacks like a heart, it must be a heart. :)

Comment: @ aL3xa Yours is the one that actually looks the most promising for my crude needs (lots of great posts here). Problem is `pch = "♥"` doesn't work for me. R converts it to a "?". I'm a windows 7 user so this may be the reason. I can use all sorts of crazy numeric values for pch but have yet to find the heart you used. Also any pointers/resources on how to determine what number coresponds to what symbol with pch would be awesome. Generally the resources I've seen have only a few symbols corresponding to numbers. I know there's 100s of them though.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker: I added a pch solution from the help(points) page. Should work if you have a Symbol font in your pdf-fonts library.

Comment: Using unicode values for pch works.  I've learned alot about symbols and just opened up a whole new bag of tricks using Unicode. `plot(1, 1, pch = -0x2665L, cex = 20, xlab = "", ylab = "", col = "firebrick3")`

Comment: As an added note the male and female symbols (thought this was only available to S users) are available through Unicode as well using: `points(1,1, pch=-0x2642L, cex = 20, col = "firebrick3") ` & `points(1,1, pch=-0x2642L, cex = 20, col = "firebrick3") ` These could be useful.

Comment: See Unicode stuff here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2665/index.htm
And frankly, I think that @DWin deserved the checkmark. My answer doesn't include a single line of maths. =/

Comment: @aL3xa Yeah this one was hard to assign credit to because they all were terrific answers.  The one that best met my needs was a simplier version of plotting symbols.  I didn't realize that until you posed it.  Per your request I assigned DWin the check.

Comment: @TylerRinker that's the spirit! Besides, he posted a larger heart! =)

Comment: I think I may have come up with a Windows-specific approach. It won't be a pch argument but you can use `text(x,y, heart, col="red")` in stead of `points(x,y,pch)`.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a cardioid in `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x=seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=100))
cardioid <- function(x, a=1)a*(1-cos(x))
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x)) + stat_function(fun=cardioid) + coord_polar()
```

[image]

And the heart plot (linked by @BenBolker):

```
heart <- function(x)2-2*sin(x) + sin(x)*(sqrt(abs(cos(x))))/(sin(x)+1.4)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x)) + stat_function(fun=heart) + coord_polar(start=-pi/2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Another option,

```
xmin <- -5
xmax <- 10
n <- 1e3
xs<-seq(xmin,xmax,length=n)
ys<-seq(xmin,xmax,length=n)

f = function(x, y) (x^2+0.7*y^2-1)^3 - x^2*y^3
zs <- outer(xs,ys,FUN=f)

h <- contourLines(xs,ys,zs,levels=0)
library(txtplot)
with(h[[1]], txtplot(x, y))



     +---+-******----+----******-+---+
 1.5 + *****    **********     ***** +
   1 +**                           * +
 0.5 +**                           * +
     | ***                       *** |
   0 +   ****                 ****   +
-0.5 +      *****         *****      +
  -1 +          ***********          +
     +---+-----+-----*-----+-----+---+
        -1   -0.5    0    0.5    1
```

Comment: ASCII art is so retro.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be more "mature",  try out the following (posted to R-help a few years ago):

```
thong<-function(h = 9){ 
     # set up plot  
    xrange=c(-15,15)  
    yrange=c(0,16)  
    plot(0,xlim=xrange,ylim=yrange,type='n')  

     # draw outer envelope  
    yr=seq(yrange[1],yrange[2],len=50)  
    offsetFn=function(y){2*sin(0+y/3)}  
    offset=offsetFn(yr)  
    leftE = function(y){-10-offsetFn(y)}  
    rightE = function(y){10+offsetFn(y)}  

    xp=c(leftE(yr),rev(rightE(yr))) 
    yp=c(yr,rev(yr))  
    polygon(xp,yp,col="#ffeecc",border=NA) 

    # feasible region upper limit: 
    # left and right defined by triple-log function:  
    xt=seq(0,rightE(h),len=100)   
    yt=log(1+log(1+log(xt+1)))   
    yt=yt-min(yt)  
    yt=h*yt/max(yt)  
    x=c(leftE(h),rightE(h),rev(xt),-xt) 
    y=c(h,h,rev(yt),yt) 
    polygon(x,y,col="red",border=NA)  
}
```

Comment: This code produced error for me.

Comment: @MYaseen208: I may have dropped a character in cut/paste.  The original code certainly works.  What error did you get?

Answer (score 3):

A few more varieties:

[image: equations]

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I think it was downvoted because it's nothing more than a link to a set of parametric equations that are linked (directly or indirectly) by several of the other answers here.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know anything about R, but if you plot this function you will get a heart:

```
x^2+(y-(x^2)^(1/3))^2=1
```