# How to draw a parametric curve in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, parametric-equations

I'd like to draw a parametric curve in ggplot2. When drawing just points, where ordering doesn't matter, it works OK:

```
library(ggplot2)
phi = seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=100)
df1 = data.frame(x=(phi+3)*cos(phi), y=(phi+3)*sin(phi))
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
```

[image: points in a spiral]

Unfortunately, ggplot2 implicitly sorts the points, so when I attempt to draw a line instead

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

I get

[image: failed spiral]

which is not what I want. The points should be connected in the same order as they are present in the dataframe. Is there a way to do it in ggplot2?

(I read the answers in [Plot a heart in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082429/plot-a-heart-in-r), but my question is specifically about ggplot2 and using polar coordinates is not an option).

Comment: Try `ggplot(data=df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_path()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
phi = seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=100)
df1 = data.frame(x=(phi+3)*cos(phi), y=(phi+3)*sin(phi))
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_path()
```

[image]